# Linear Regression calculation several times in one dataframe

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I am using R to evaluate climate data and I have a data set that looks like the following miniaturized version... please forgive my crude posting etiquette, I hope this post is understandable.

```
[0][STA.NAME] [YEAR] [SUM.CDD]  
1 NAME1 1967    760  
2 NAME1 1985    800  
3 NAME1 1996    740  
4 NAME1 2003    810  
5 NAME1 2011    790  
6 NAME2 1967    700  
7 NAME2 1985    690  
8 NAME2 1996    850  
9 NAME2 2003    790  
10 NAME3    1967    760  
11 NAME3    1985    800  
12 NAME3    1990    740  
13 NAME3    1996    810  
14 NAME3    2003    790  
15 NAME3    2011    800
```

I am trying to return a new DF with this

```
[STA.NAME] [Eq'n of trend]  
NAME1  (y = mx + b)  
NAME2  (y = mx + b)
```

etc...

Eventually I will need to calculate variance of the trends, as well as total variance of data and would like to eventually append those to this resulting data set for something like...

```
[STA.NAME] [TREND] [VAR.TREND] [VAR.DATA]   
with values in rows, 1 for each STA.NAME...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, If there is a better way than lm(), with which I am currently stumped, I would be interested as well.

Thank you very much,

Jesse

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple solution using `ddply()` from `plyr` to return the coefficients for each group:

First replicate the data:

```
x <- read.table(text="
STA.NAME YEAR SUM.CDD  
1 NAME1 1967    760  
2 NAME1 1985    800  
3 NAME1 1996    740  
4 NAME1 2003    810  
5 NAME1 2011    790  
6 NAME2 1967    700  
7 NAME2 1985    690  
8 NAME2 1996    850  
9 NAME2 2003    790  
10 NAME3    1967    760  
11 NAME3    1985    800  
12 NAME3    1990    740  
13 NAME3    1996    810  
14 NAME3    2003    790  
15 NAME3    2011    800  ", header=TRUE)
```

Now do the modelling:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(x, .(STA.NAME), function(z)coef(lm(SUM.CDD ~ YEAR, data=z)))

  STA.NAME (Intercept)      YEAR
1    NAME1   -444.8361 0.6147541
2    NAME2  -6339.2047 3.5702200
3    NAME3   -995.2381 0.8928571
```

---

Now, depending on what you want to do, it may be simpler (and perhaps more meaningful) to create a single model of your data:

```
fit <- lm(SUM.CDD ~ YEAR + STA.NAME, data=x)
```

Get a summary:

```
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = SUM.CDD ~ YEAR + STA.NAME, data = x)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-63.57 -22.21  10.72  18.62  80.72 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   -2065.6401  1463.5353  -1.411   0.1858  
YEAR              1.4282     0.7345   1.945   0.0778 .
STA.NAMENAME2   -15.8586    27.5835  -0.575   0.5769  
STA.NAMENAME3     3.9046    24.7089   0.158   0.8773  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 40.8 on 11 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.3056, Adjusted R-squared: 0.1162 
F-statistic: 1.614 on 3 and 11 DF,  p-value: 0.2424
```

Extract only the coefficients:

```
coef(fit)
  (Intercept)          YEAR STA.NAMENAME2 STA.NAMENAME3 
 -2065.640078      1.428247    -15.858650      3.904632
```

---

Finally, you perhaps wanted to fit a model with interaction terms. This model gives you effectively the same results as the original `plyr` solution. Depending on your data and your objectives, this might be the way to do it:

```
fit <- lm(SUM.CDD ~ YEAR * STA.NAME, data=x)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = SUM.CDD ~ YEAR * STA.NAME, data = x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-57.682 -13.166  -1.012  23.006  63.046 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         -444.8361  2280.7464  -0.195    0.850
YEAR                   0.6148     1.1447   0.537    0.604
STA.NAMENAME2      -5894.3687  3661.9795  -1.610    0.142
STA.NAMENAME3       -550.4020  3221.8390  -0.171    0.868
YEAR:STA.NAMENAME2     2.9555     1.8406   1.606    0.143
YEAR:STA.NAMENAME3     0.2781     1.6172   0.172    0.867

Residual standard error: 39.17 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4763, Adjusted R-squared: 0.1854 
F-statistic: 1.637 on 5 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.2451
```

Comment: Very nice layout, even by your high standards :-) . Sticking `lm` inside the `ddply` call is not only cool, but highlights the power of `plyr` tools in general.

Comment: again, Thank you very much. Very clean, I did not understand the ~ modeling syntax very well but your code makes it quite understandable.
Thanks again, Jesse

Comment: @user1680636 If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green tick mark. This indicates to others that the question was answered.

Comment: @Andrie @user1680636 This is a great answer. May I also add that one can directly get the same stratified coefficients as with the `ddply()` call, by using `coef(lm(SUM.CDD ~ STA.NAME + YEAR:STA.NAME, data=x))`.

Comment: @TheodoreLytras Yes, `a*b` is the same as `a + a:b`

Comment: @Andrie Actually `a*b` is the same as `a + b + a:b`. It includes in the model _both_ terms and their interaction. `a + a:b`, where `a` is a factor, includes `a` and the stratified effect of `b` on each level of `a`. It's not equivalent, and one doesn't get the same coefficients.